# Entlib 4.1 in Partial Trust on Azure?

Tags: entity-framework, azure

I am using (or want to use) Entlib 4.1 for Logging in a small app I am building for the Azure Platform - the problem is that I keep getting security exceptions related to Partial Trust?

Does anyone know how to correctly set partial trust for azure ? Or has done so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add enableNativeCodeExecution="true" to your .csdef file.  This will let you run in full trust.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, we published a whitepaper for Enterprise Library (5.0) on Windows Azure considerations [here](http://wag.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?DownloadId=111359).